# How to find the contour which is nearest to the center of image?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

How to find the contour that is nearest to the center of image?

For example in the image below, I have used cv::findContours() to find two contours of an image(please ignore the 5pixel part as I have used this image in another SO post), is it possible to locate the contour index of the red contour which is nearest to the center of image?

[image: Imgur]

I currently used cv::pointPolygonTest and loop the contours with the coordinate of the center of image to find the distance between every contours and center, it feel inefficient, is there any opencv function I can use?

Comment: Where is the center of the image?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I have edited the image, the black dot is the center of image

Comment: Inside the image where is the contour and what do you mean by 5pixel? In your image, the contour already is in the center.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Ignore the 5 pixel. The red line and the black line are the two contours I found using findContours(). How can I get the index of the red contour?